# Smoke simulation disappears after 10 to 20 frames

Tags: particles, smoke-simulation

I'm trying to understand how mantaflow works.

Every time I create a smoke simulation the smoke disappears after a couple of frames. It seems the simulation is still calculating all the data since the cache folder contains data for every frame with increasing size.

In this scene I only like to create a dust trail, emitted from particles behind the robots wheel. As you can see in my screenshots the smoke is present at frame 1 as expected. But this small smoke cloud is all that I can get.

[image]

The robot keeps driving and the particles keep flowing - but no smoke is emitted from anywhere. With density cranked up I can still render the smoke in frame 20 - but after that it's gone.

[image]

Some additional information: I have the same issue when creating smoke from a stationary emitter. I created the scene first in blender 2.91.2 and then changed to blender 2.82 in the hope to get the simulation running properly.

I read the posts in this forum that suggest to change substeps or increase the smoke domain size. But I tried everything I could come up with with absolutely no effect.

Do you guys have any idea what I could try?

Comment: Just to doublecheck, is the smoke source set to inflow instead of mesh.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It is of course set to 'inflow'. I tried it several times again with different versions. And it suddenly worked with blender 2.90. I am just using this bake now since the result is pretty much what I wanted. 

But I think it might just be a bug. Otherwise it would either work or not. ‍♀️

I got to admit: I almost gave up with blenders smoke simulations. I bought the "Storm Simulation Tool" which comes with it's own problems - but at least the baking time is a fraction compared to blender. So I hope to save some time that way.

Comment: But I will try 2.92 for simulation. I just have to finish this project first.